# Why doesn't perf report cache misses?

Tags: linux, caching, optimization, profiling, perf

According to [perf tutorials](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), `perf stat` is supposed to report cache misses using hardware counters. However, on my system (up-to-date Arch Linux), it doesn't:

```
[joel@panda goog]$ perf stat ./hash

 Performance counter stats for './hash':

    869.447863 task-clock                #    0.997 CPUs utilized          
            92 context-switches          #    0.106 K/sec                  
             4 cpu-migrations            #    0.005 K/sec                  
         1,041 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
 2,628,646,296 cycles                    #    3.023 GHz                    
   819,269,992 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   31.17% frontend cycles idle   
   132,355,435 stalled-cycles-backend    #    5.04% backend  cycles idle   
 4,515,152,198 instructions              #    1.72  insns per cycle        
                                         #    0.18  stalled cycles per insn
 1,060,739,808 branches                  # 1220.015 M/sec                  
     2,653,157 branch-misses             #    0.25% of all branches        

   0.871766141 seconds time elapsed
```

What am I missing? I already searched the man page and the web, but didn't find anything obvious.

Edit: my CPU is an Intel i5 2300K, if that matters.

Comment: It depends on your hardware counters. I've never used `perf`, but I've used `PAPI` (http://icl.cs.utk.edu/PAPI/) and it's possible to check the available hardware counters to find out what can you get from your CPU.

Comment: Try `perf stat -d` - it will report some cache events. Check also new `perf mem` tool for record/report memory events - documented in http://www.linuxtag.org/2013/fileadmin/www.linuxtag.org/slides/Arnaldo_Melo_-_Linux__perf__tools__Overview_and_Current_Developments.e323.pdf slide 10 and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-mem.1.html

Comment: osgx, `perf stat -d` will turn on event multiplexing, which sometimes may report incorrect rates. It is better to manually select no more than 5-7 hw events per run; and use perf stat -d only to get names of such events. Other way for Intel - try toplev.py from https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools

Answer (score 59, accepted):

On my system, an `Intel Xeon X5570 @ 2.93 GHz` I was able to get `perf stat` to report cache references and misses by requesting those events explicitly like this

```
perf stat -B -e cache-references,cache-misses,cycles,instructions,branches,faults,migrations sleep 5
Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':

         10573 cache-references                                            
          1949 cache-misses              #   18.434 % of all cache refs    
       1077328 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz                    
        715248 instructions              #    0.66  insns per cycle        
        151188 branches                                                    
           154 faults                                                      
             0 migrations                                                  

   5.002776842 seconds time elapsed
```

The default set of events did not include cache events, matching your results, I don't know why

```
perf stat -B sleep 5

Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':

      0.344308 task-clock                #    0.000 CPUs utilized          
             1 context-switches          #    0.003 M/sec                  
             0 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
           154 page-faults               #    0.447 M/sec                  
        977183 cycles                    #    2.838 GHz                    
        586878 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   60.06% frontend cycles idle   
        430497 stalled-cycles-backend    #   44.05% backend  cycles idle   
        720815 instructions              #    0.74  insns per cycle        
                                         #    0.81  stalled cycles per insn
        152217 branches                  #  442.095 M/sec                  
          7646 branch-misses             #    5.02% of all branches        

   5.002763199 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I guess they must have changed the default set of events that are captured.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking it was weird to have to always record the info.. This approach is faster :)

Comment: A question inside the question, What is the `fauts` count in the perf output

Comment: @ElvisTeixeira `faults` is an alias for `page-faults`, for a list of all events run  `perf list`

Comment: tnks @amdn. Now, what are `page-faults`?

Comment: Is there a way to get cache misses per function call like you'd normally see in a `perf report`?

Answer (score 17):

In [the latest source code](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?id=refs/tags/v4.3#n975), the default event does not include `cache-misses` and `cache-references` again:

```
struct perf_event_attr default_attrs[] = {

  { .type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK      },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES    },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_SW_CPU_MIGRATIONS      },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS     },

  { .type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES      },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_STALLED_CYCLES_FRONTEND },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_STALLED_CYCLES_BACKEND  },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS        },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_INSTRUCTIONS },
  { .type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES       },

};
```

So the man and most web are out of date as so far.

Answer (score 4):

I've spent some minutes trying to understand `perf`. I found out the cache-misses by first recording and then reporting the data (both `perf` tools).

To see a list of events:

```
perf list
```

For example, in order to check the last-level-cache load misses, you will need to use the event `LLC-loads-misses` like this

```
perf record -e LLC-loads-misses ./your_program
```

then report the results

```
perf report -v
```

Comment: What's the difference between the perf events `cache-misses` and `LLC-loads-misses`?

Comment: It's been a long while since I looked at these things, but I think the cache-misses include misses for all levels of the cache (typically 3 levels) and LLC might only be for the last level L3, because that's the most critical one, if it misses there it goes to the memory.